# problemas con window is not defined next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

estoy pasando mi proyecto de `react-app` a `nextJs` y el problema que me sale es que en next js un codigo me sale como `window is not defined next js` y no se como solucionarlo, este seria mo codigo que me da error

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Login from "./Login";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";

const code = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("code");

function App() {
  return code ? <Dashboard code={code} /> : <Login />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: NextJS ejecuta código tanto en el servidor como en el cliente. Si mueves la llamada a window a componentDidMount, estarás ejecutando ese fragmento en el lado del cliente, donde window si existe.

Comment: como podria pasarlo a componentDidMount, aun no comprendo tanto haha lo siento @Jacobo

Comment: Sobreescribes el método `componentDidMount`, aunque no estoy muy seguro de como hacer el refresh de tu componente para que tome el nuevo valor de code.